# Grep and Cut Command and divide string

Tags: grep, cut, divide

I have a grep command that gives the following string:

```
20121121001100 18 0 16 2 18
```

but I would like to modify this string to get

```
20121121 001 18 0 16 2 18
```

the above value are being extracted by the following:

```
for i in `ls -1 file.txt | sort`; do echo $i`
grep datetime $i | wc -l ``
grep abc $i | wc -l ``
grep def $i | wc -l ``
grep ghi $i | wc -l ``
grep jkl $i | wc -l ` ; done | cut -c9-500
```

cut -c9-500 is used because the original string is in the form of

```
datetime20121121001100 18 0 16 2 18
```

and cut -c9-500 returns

```
20121121001100 18 0 16 2 18
```

Can someone please help me to get

```
20121121 001 18 0 16 2 18
```

(ie remove the last 3 digits from the date part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you want/do can be accomplished with `awk`. But for the minimum you want:

```
for i in `ls -1 file.txt | sort`; do echo $i`
grep datetime $i | wc -l ``
grep abc $i | wc -l ``
grep def $i | wc -l ``
grep ghi $i | wc -l ``
grep jkl $i | wc -l ` ; done | cut -c9-500 | awk '{print substr($0,1,11) substr($0,15) }'
```

`awk` is very capable at text processing.

Edit: I'm not sure of what are you doing, but, basicly this does (almost) the same:

```
awk 'FILENAME != oldfilename {oldfilename = FILENAME; dt = 0 ; a = 0; d = 0; g = 0; j = 0}
     /datetime/ {dt++}
     /abc/ {a++}
     /def/ {d++}
     /ghi/ {g++}
     /j/ {j++}
     END {print FILENAME, dt, a, d, g, j}' *
```

And it's faster, fewer processes, etc... Basically awk process the file, counts the occurences of the specified strings, and when it finishes the file (after the last line) prints the report.

Changed specs:

```
for i in `ls -1 file.txt | sort`; do echo $i`
grep datetime $i | wc -l ``
grep abc $i | wc -l ``
grep def $i | wc -l ``
grep ghi $i | wc -l ``
grep jkl $i | wc -l ` ; done | cut -c9-500 | awk '{print substr($0,1,8) " " substr($0,9,4) substr($0,15) }'
```

Comment: thanks .... re"after the last line will print report" will the use a large amount of memory?

Comment: Nope, as you can see it will count in 5 variables (which are reset for every file), so most probably modern machines (after ummm 1960) can deal with it.

Comment: thanks .... you first suggestion worked fine! can you please arrange your command to get "20121121 0010" instead of "20121121001 " ?

Comment: yes ... but now the spec changed a bit :) ... is it possible to get "20121121 0010"?

Comment: Yes it is. see this page: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ (and I'm editing the post...)?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe to sed:

```
echo "20121121001100 18 0 16 2 18" | sed -r 's/^([0-9]+)[0-9][0-9][0-9] (.*)$/\1 \2/'
```

gives

```
20121121001 18 0 16 2 18
```

Comment: can you add the above to my grep command cause i cannot understand how to implement it.

Comment: @mouthpiec: Just pipe the output from your cut command to the sed command above.